# Food Ingredients Complex Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

hi i have 3 tables named : foods, ingredients & foods_ingredients (which is many to many relation)

each ingredient has expires_at & stock property

i want to write a complex query which enables me to fetch foods name by their stock and expires date

This is my own Query but Expire Comparison not working

```
SELECT * 
FROM `foods`
LEFT JOIN `foods_ingredients` ON foods_ingredients.food_id = foods.id
LEFT JOIN `ingredients` ON foods_ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients.id
WHERE foods.id IN 
    (SELECT `food_id` 
     FROM `ingredients` 
     LEFT JOIN `foods_ingredients` ON foods_ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients.id 
     WHERE ingredients.stock > 0 AND ingredients.expires_at > CURRENT_DATE)
ORDER BY `best_before` DESC;
```

Comment: Please add table description, some example datas and expected result all in text format. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update the question. Check [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Your question does not specify why you need LEFT JOIN? You could just change them to INNER JOINs, remove the subquery and put the stock/expires criteria in the main query.

Comment: Why does it have to be a complex query?

Comment: What does "Expire Comparison not working" mean? What's not working?

Comment: @HoneyBadger i want to fetch all Available foods based on Ingredients (Stock field in this table most be greater than 0)

Comment: ingredients also has an expires_at column which effects returned foods

Comment: @tinazmu not working . still returns foods that arent available (based on ingredient stock)

Comment: Did you want to see all ingredients of all food items where all ingredients for that recipe are available and not expired? İf this the case we can change your original query to exclude those where any ingredient has 0 stock or expired

Comment: @tinazmu dear tina , i want to see all foods based on Ingredients (stock / expire_date)

Comment: Can stock be null? Or is it always a number?

Comment: @tinazmu always an integer 0 or greater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selects all foods & food_items where all ingredients (for those foods) exist (not expired, and stock gt 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `foods` f
 
  INNER JOIN `foods_ingredients` fi
  ON fi.food_id = f.id
  
  INNER JOIN `ingredients` i
  ON fi.ingredient_id = i.id

WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT *
         FROM `ingredients` ib
              INNER JOIN
              `foods_ingredients` fib 
              on ib.id=fib.ingredient_id
         WHERE fib.food_id=f.f.food_id
               and (ib.stock = 0 or ib.expires_at <= CURRENT_DATE)
        )
ORDER BY `best_before` DESC
```

This assumes that you don't want to see foods/food_items if one or more ingredients for that foods item is stock=0 or expired.

It also assumes that you have the relevant rows in all tables (rows exist) for all ingredients even if those ingredients are zero stock or expired.